# Getting to know manager

Tags: manager

I have a part time lifeguard job at a hotel where one of the managers is basically the same age as me (I’m 24 she’s 23). I have heard of others who are younger than me inviting her to do things outside of work and she seems to like going out with them since she is from out of state.

I have  social anxiety and would love to ask her to do something outside of work but am afraid of being shot down and I have know idea how to approach it.

I would love to get to know her better because I really only see her like 4 times a month at work because of the shifts she works.

I’ve always had anxiety as I don’t really have a lot of friends. I have trouble communicating with others to find interests and starting a conversation or keeping one going on as well

Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Is there a chance that your manager would construe this as asking for a date?

Comment: Nope! Not that I have seen or heard of.

Comment: Note: this may be better for interpersonal stack exchange.

Comment: @MichaelMcFarlane While there is an IPS question here, the essence here is very much "navigating the workplace" given the OP is talking about getting to know their manager so I don't think there's any problem with asking it here

Comment: Can you join with the "I have heard of others inviting her to do things" and be part of a group event?

Comment: Placing this on hold since it's unclear what you're asking: is it about how to navigate meeting your manager outside of work to get to know them better as a person with a mind to having a better professional relationship? Or is about anxiety related to asking people out in general?

Comment: Getting to know them better in a professional relationship level

Answer (score 2):

Assuming this won't be construed as inappropriate (e.g. not as a date), I suggest the following.

0. Enter the conversation with a plan of what activity you might do, depending on your interests, and hers if you can ascertain that. They should be low-key, like coffee, meeting with the other friends, etc.
1. Gauge her interest with non-committal chit chat about activities. For instance, "You must be busy this weekend" or "so you like [doing thing]". This gives her a chance to prevent this from going forward if she needs to. She might say "my family is in town" or "my basement is flooding". Then you can abort for the time being. If she's interested, she'll reciprocate by extending the conversation about activities. She may say, "I'm not too busy. You?" or "yeah, I'm always up for [thing]. What about you?" If you get that opening, then you can proceed to 2.
2. Connect the conversation to something you thought about in 0. Tell her that you plan to do [activity], and ask if she would like to do so too. It's useful to say you already plan to do it because that's clear and takes pressure off her.

If that's too abstract, then perhaps you can talk to the friends that have hung out with her and ask if you could tag along, or ask for advice.

Just remember if she rejects you it may be for random reasons. You can never know what's in her mind, so try not to take it perconally unless she is explicitly mean.

Comment: For somebody with social anxiety such a detailed and construed plan for just asking somebody for a coffee or similar after work might be a little of a challenge and could end up in an ackward situation. I think a simple aproach like _"I'm visiting todays flea-market after work - wanna join?"_ would be a simpler stunt to pull off.. Though I like the idea in your second last paragraph (hence +1)  - with somebody else around it  would also ease the situation a bit..